# Diferenças de global scope em UserScripts no Chrome e Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, variáveis-globais, userscripts

Comecei a programar UserScripts no Chrome e quase todos os *snippets* de código que encontro funcionam, mas na hora de ir pro Firefox dá problema. No Chrome uso o [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) e no Firefox o [Scriptish](http://scriptish.org/) (que é um *fork* do Greasemonkey).

<sup><sub>*[Nota aos futuros visitantes, desaconselho **enfaticamente** trabalhar com o Scriptish, tem coisas que rodam tranquilamente no GM e TM mas não nele.]*</sub></sup>

Por exemplo, se adiciono um script na DOM, cujo retorno é um JSONP, a função `callback` (global) do JSONP dá `undefined` no FF. Ou então, se faço uma chamada AJAX, na hora do executar uma função global dentro do `success` também dá `undefined` no FF.

Fiz uma versão reduzida que demonstra o problema. A função `global_function` roda no Chrome mas não no FF. O domínio de execução é o SOPT e a chamada AJAX é ao API do Stack Exchange.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           (SOPT) FF problems
// @namespace      sopt.se
// @author         brasofilo
// @include        http://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @description    Testando problemas no FF
// ==/UserScript==

jquery_url = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

global_function = function() {
    alert( 'yes!' );
}

/**
 * Chamada depois que o jQuery foi carregado
 */
function jqueryLoaded() {
    jQ.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users',
        data: { order: 'desc', sort: 'reputation', site: 'stackoverflow' },
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            global_function();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Carrega jQuery e chama callback quando carregar
 * Nota: jQ substitui $ para evitar conflitos
 * 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/3550261/1287812
 */
function addJQuery( callback ) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.setAttribute( 'src', jquery_url );
script.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = 'window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(' + callback.toString() + ')();';
        document.body.appendChild( script );
    }, false );
    document.body.appendChild( script );
}

addJQuery( jqueryLoaded );
```

Tentei `window.global_function = function(){ }`, `function global_function() {}`, `unsafeWindow.global_function = function(){ }` e segue `undefined`. E conferi as seguintes discussões mas não esclareci nada...

- [Greasemonkey Script and Function Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551028/greasemonkey-script-and-function-scope)
- [Greasemonkey & global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321978/greasemonkey-global-variables)
- [Greasemonkey Script and Function Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551028/greasemonkey-script-and-function-scope)

Como resolver essa questão de *scope*? E além disso, existem outras diferenças básicas ao programar UserScripts para o Chrome e para o Firefox?

Comment: O Stackoverflow já carrega o jQuery. O cógido que vc rodar dentro de script tags poderia acessar o jquery do stackoverflow sem precisar carregar a biblioteca denovo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por razões de segurança<sup>1</sup>, userscripts do greasemonkey rodam em um sandbox separado dos scripts normais da sua página. Em particular, o script greasemonkey tem uma `window` diferende da `window` do resto dos scripts da página: variáveis globais definidas no userscript não vazam pros scripts da página e vice versa.

Em particular, o código dentro das tags script que você criou vai rodar no contexto da página, que é diferente do contexto original do seu userscript.

Os links que você encontrou sugerem usar a propriedade unsafeWindow para acessar a window da página a partir da window do greasemonkey mas isso infelizmente não funciona mais, já que o Firefox recentemente [removeu o suporte a unsafeWindow](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/), que deixou de poder ser usado pelo greasemonkey a partir da [versão 2.0](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html).

Para resolver o seu problema, tem mais de uma abordagem que você pode tomar:

- Use a a nova API [export_function](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/) para exportar global_function do escopo do greasemonkey para o escopo da página, onde você está carregando o jQuery.

  Acho que essa solução só funciona no Firefox.
- Carregue o jQuery no escopo do script greasemonkey, usando [require](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Third-Party_Libraries). Assim o seu código roda todo no escopo do greasemonkey e você pode ignorar o escopo da página (e tags de script inseridas dinâmicamente).

  Acho que evitar tags script dinâmicas seria a solução menos "gambiarra". O problema é que não sei se dá pra fazer isso no tampermonkey e nem toda biblioteca que vc quiser usar aceita ser rodada no escopo do greasemonkey.
- Faça o oposto da segunda alternativa: rode seu cógigo todo no escopo da página e ignore o escopo do greasemonkey. A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso seria por todas as suas funções dentro do jqueryLoaded, que é a função que vc está serializando pra dentro da script tag:

  ```
  function jQueryLoaded(){
      function global_function(){ ... }

      jQ.ajax({
          success: function(){
               global_function();
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  Botar o seu código todo dentro da tag script injetada é bem simples e "cross browser" e também é a única forma de sobrescrever variáveis definidas pelos scripts da página (se vc precisar fazer isso). A desvantagem principal é que os números das linhas das mensagens de erro que você obtém não batem com os números de linha do seu arquivo original.

---

<sup>1</sup> O greasemonkey disponibiliza algumas APIs mais privilegiadas, que não queremos que sejam acessadas pelos scripts que carregamos da web.